# Word embeddings for phrases

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, word-embedding

I have a dataset, which contains of approx. 50k records of job titles. For example:

1. Python Developer
2. Java Developer
3. Accountant
4. Salesman
5. Developer
6. Programmer

etc. (Job titles are in german, but for explanation it doesn't matter)

I want to cluster similar jobs and for this i want to use word embeddings of each job title. For this I have chosen spaCy library

```
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")
```

Almost every single word has an embedding representation. For example: python, developer, etc. But if I define them together as phrase('Python Developer'), this it doesn't have embedding representation.

How should I create word embeddings of the combination of words (like "Python Developer")?